# ¿Como Marcar o Desmarcar CheckBox?

Tags: ios, swift2, swift

Necesito ayuda con unos checkbox personalizados.

Para hacerlos puse dos botones y cree dos clases , una para cada checkbox que les da su forma el cual saque de este mismo sitio, les dejo la clase con la que le doy forma al boton

```
import UIKit

class CheckBox: UIButton {
// Images
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_check_box")! as UIImage
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_check_box_outline_blank")! as UIImage

// Bool property
var isChecked: Bool = false {
    didSet{
        if isChecked == true {
            self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
        } else {
            self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender == self {
        isChecked = !isChecked
    }
}
}
```

lo que necesito es guia para que al estar marcado un checkbox el otro se desmarque, dejo una imagen de guia

[image: checkbox_1]

[image: checkbox_2]

Comment: Te recomiendo esta libreria https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox Yo la use y me funcionó muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas una clase personalizada para el check , solo puedes controlar tu estado osea a ser el del botón pulsado , lo que deberías hacer para controlar que si tienes un botón marcado el otro se desmarque , es crear simplemente una función que compruebe que si has pulsado sobre el SI desmarque el No y a la inversa.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué no utilizar una librería que ya lo hace?
Intenta con [CheckboxButton](https://github.com/chrisamanse/CheckboxButton) de [Chris Amanse](https://github.com/chrisamanse) es muy simple y hace exactamente lo que necesitas:

`CheckboxButton` cambia de estado cada vez que un evento `.TouchUpInside` ocurre. Y puedes registrar los cambios de estado utilizando el evento `UIControlEvents.ValueChanged`.

Las validaciones son tan simples como:

```
if checkbox.on {
  print("Checkbox is checked")
}

// Toggle
checkbox.on = false // Set to false to uncheck
```

Lo puedes instalar con [Carthage](https://github.com/carthage/carthage) agregando `github "chrisamanse/CheckboxButton"` a tu `Cartfile`, o manualmente copiando simplemente el archivo `CheckboxButton.swift` a tu poyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que podrías ligarlos de alguna forma para que uno mande a llamar al otro, o sea agregas una propiedad (weak) ** otroBoton**.

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {
// Images
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_check_box")! as UIImage
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_check_box_outline_blank")! as UIImage

// el otro botón 
weak var otroBoton:UIButton!

// Bool property
var isChecked: Bool = false {
    didSet{

        if isChecked == true {
            self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
        } else {
            self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }
         // Solo si son iguales para evitar un ciclo infinito 
         if self.otroBoton.isChecked == self.isChecked {
         // Invertimos el valor para que siempre tengan el opuesto del otro 
             self.otroBoton.isChecked = !self.isChecked
         }

    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender == self {
        isChecked = !isChecked
    }
}
}
```